# How to build a class with properites by traversing a graph in gremlin-scala?

Tags: scala, gremlin

I am using the library [gremlin-scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala)  with apache tinkergraph. How can I create a class with properties collected by traversing a graph?

```
Mark --lives--> Kenya
Mark --lives--> Europe
Mark --lives--> US
Mark -- studyingAt --> XYZ college --locatedIn--> US

Student(name: String, livedAt: List[String], collegeName)

g.V.hasLabel("Mark")....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of using Object Graph Mapping frameworks, I think it might be best to use a `Map` based argument to your constructor for `Student` and then write your Gremlin so that it returns a `Map` that fits the expected format. For example, consider your sample graph (when asking Gremlin questions it's best to include a little sample graph creation script that can be pasted into a console):

```
g.addV('Mark').as('m').
  addV('Kenya').as('k').
  addV('Europe').as('e').
  addV('US').as('u').
  addV('XYZ college').as('x').
  addE('studyingAt').from('m').to('x').
  addE('lives').from('m').to('k').
  addE('lives').from('m').to('e').
  addE('lives').from('m').to('u').iterate()
```

Just a quick side-note (though I assume it's obvious) that this isn't a great graph schema design - "Mark" and the country/college names should be properties not vertex labels. Anyway, I produce the `Map` with the data you wanted for your `Student` class here:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Mark').
......1>   project('name','livedAt','collegeName').
......2>     by(label).
......3>     by(out('lives').label().fold()).
......4>     by(out('studyingAt').label())
==>[name:Mark,livedAt:[Kenya,Europe,US],collegeName:XYZ college]
```

Just pass that result into your `Student` class constructor. While you should typically try to avoid lambda expressions you could also add a `map()` step to the end of that traversal and construct the `Student` there.